# TempData set in @Html.Action() is not accessible in other actions of same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I have a view which gets rendered using `@HTML.Action("Action1", {guid = Model.guid})` and I create and set some `TempData` inside this Action 1. But these `TempData`s are not available on other actions of same controller.

View(Parent View)

```
<div style="Display:block" id="divUserTeamDetails">
    <div id="UserTeamDetailsContainer">
        @Html.Action("Action1", new { guid = Model.guid })
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Action1(int pageSize = 10, int page = 1, string sort = "TeamName", string sortdir = "ASC")
{
    ....
    foreach (var item in obj1.UserIdRowIdentifier)
    {
        if (!TempData.ContainsKey(BaseGuid + '_' + item.Value))
        {
            TempData[BaseGuid + '_' + item.Value] = item.Key;
            TempData["temp1" + BaseGuid + '_' + item.Value] = TempData[BaseGuid + '_' + item.Value];
        }
    }
    return View("view1", model1);
}
```

Comment: Add the controller code please.

Comment: We cannot guess what your code is or what mistakes your making.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Tempdata.Keep() method to store data into Tempdata

Comment: TempData created here is different from the TempData available on other actions as the count of TempData inside this action is 0 while in other action count of TempData around 100.

Comment: Value of TempData is no persisiting..It means U need to persist data present in Tempdata.We can do this by using Keep method of TempData